# Is sshd hard-coded to require root access?

Tags: linux, sshd

I am attempting to run an SSH daemon as a non-root user, as I want to provide SSH access to our Git repositories on a server which I do not have root access for.  I have got it to run using a custom configuration and local certificates, but logins are not currently working.

I am using the following version of `sshd`:

> OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

I am not looking for help with the configuration, etc. at this stage (I will post separate questions, if necessary).  I just want to know whether there are hard-coded limitations that mean this is impossible before I invest any more time in this.

Are there any hard limits in the SSH daemon that prevent it from being used successfully as a non-root user?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I don't think so. You will likely have difficulties changing user if you don't start as root though, and you will have to change the port it listens on > 1023 as only root can bind to low ports like 22.

Comment: It is possible to run openssh as a non root user however you can only log in as the user running the openssh process. You also need to disable `UsePrivilegeSeparation` so you can't use OpenSSH 7.5 or newer. In your ssh config you need to point all files to something your regular user can access and make sure you use a non privileged port. And I seem to remember you can only use keybased authentication but it's been so long since I tried it I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: @HoD - That sounds like an answer, rather than a comment.  Care to add it?

Comment: Re: *"And I seem to remember you can only use keybased authentication"* - I did a bit of digging and it looks like [the code in auth.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/d4f4cdd681ab6408a98419f398b75a55497ed324/auth.c#L583) uses the `getpwnam()` system call to perform password-based authentication, which by my understanding is hard-coded to read from `/etc/passwd`.  Therefore, presumably, you won't be able to use this method if not running as root due to permissions on that file.  Can't comment on any other authentication methods.

Comment: It's the beginning of an answer, but it's all from memory from a few years ago.. It started as a simpler comment but I got carried away :)

Comment: @HoD - I've done a bunch of research which backs up everything you said and have written this up into a proper answer, including relevant links/citations.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the input - I have incoporated this aspect into my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I've discovered, based on a fair amount of research:

- **root is required if using OpenSSH v7.5 or above.**

  From this version onwards the `UsePrivilegeSeparation` option has been removed and this feature is [now always enabled](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.5).  This means that the SSH daemon needs to be able to run sub-processes as a different user, which requires root.
- **root is required if using the `AuthorizedKeyCommands` option**.

  When [the specified script is run](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/96bd895a0a0b3a36f81c14db8c91513578fc5563/auth2-pubkey.c#L969) the [safe_mode check is configured to always use the root user](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/d4f4cdd681ab6408a98419f398b75a55497ed324/auth.c#L894) (uid = 0) and so [it fails](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/6c6072ba8b079e6f5caa38b011a6f4570c14ed38/misc.c#L1912) if the script is owned by someone other than root.  This is [by design](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2092).  (I should also note that the `StrictModes` flag sounds like it will disable these mode checks, but it does not.)
- **root is required if you want to use standard password authentication.**

  Normal passwords are checked [using the `getpwname()` system call](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/d4f4cdd681ab6408a98419f398b75a55497ed324/auth.c#L583) which is hard-coded to look in `/etc/shadow` which is only readable by root.
- **root is required if you want to run on a port < 1024**

  Ports 0-1023 are [privileged](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) and can only be used by the root user.  This means you can't run on standard SSH port 22 and any connections to the daemon would therefore require a port to be explicitly specified.

Therefore, it *may* be possible to run it as root if:

1. You are using OpenSSH < 7.5
2. You disable `UsePrivilegeSeparation`
3. Your authentication method is by public key
4. You are happy to run the daemon on port 1024 or above

I have not investigated further as my use-case requires `AuthorizedKeyCommands` and so I've reached a dead-end.  There may be further restrictions for non-root users that you might encounter even if the above conditions are met, however I have [found some evidence that people have been able to run it as non-root, in some situations](https://serverfault.com/questions/344295/is-it-possible-to-run-sshd-as-a-normal-user).

### A couple of edge-cases

Just for completeness, there are a couple of edge-cases to the above rules.  I have not tested these; they are based on deductions from the code that I encountered whilst investigating the above:

- If your system stores user passwords in `/etc/passwd` rather than `/etc/shadow` then it *may* be possible to use password-based authentication as that file is world-readable and there don't appear to be any explicit mode checks for this in the OpenSSH code.  However, it is **really, really dangerous** to configure your system in this manner, so don't ever do it!
- If you use `AuthorizedKeyCommands` to point to a script that is owned by root but executable by your user account, then it *may* be possible to use this form of authentication.  However, the script would still need to have write-access disabled for group/other so you wouldn't be able to create or edit the file except as root, which prevents this from being a solution if you do not have root access at all.